# Python get keys from unbound TypedDict

Tags: python, dictionary, type-hinting, python-typing

I would like to get the keys from an unbound `TypedDict` subclass.

What is the correct way to do so?

Below I have a hacky method, and I'm wondering if there's a more standard way.

---

**Current Method**

I used `inspect.getmembers` on the `TypedDict` subclass, and saw the `__annotations__` attribute houses a mapping of the keys + type annotations.  From there, I use `.keys()` to get access to all of the keys.

```py
from typing_extensions import TypedDict


class SomeTypedDict(TypedDict):

    key1: str
    key2: int


print(SomeTypedDict.__annotations__.keys())
```

Prints: `dict_keys(['key1', 'key2'])`

This does work, but I am wondering, is there a better/more standard way?

---

**Versions**

```
python==3.6.5
typing-extensions==3.7.4.2
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [code documentation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ac38a9f2dfbba95f5d4338eb11a0221d38ef9328/Lib/typing.py#L2290-L2291) explicitly states (referring to a sample derived class `Point2D`):

> The type info can be accessed via the `Point2D.__annotations__` dict, and the `Point2D.__required_keys__` and `Point2D.__optional_keys__` frozensets.

So if the modules code says this, there is no reason to look for another method.

Note that your method only printed the names of the dictionary keys. You can get the names and the type simply by accessing the full dictionary:

```
print(SomeTypedDict.__annotations__)
```

Which will get you back all the info:

```
{'key1': <class 'str'>, 'key2': <class 'int'>}
```

Comment: `Point2D.__required_keys__` and `Point2D.__optional_keys__` don't seem to be available in 3.8. Were they removed for some reason?

Comment: It was added in 3.9: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/typing.py#L1973-L1974 In 3.8, no such thing: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/typing.py#L1712-L1757

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_type_hints` function.

```py
from typing import TypedDict, get_type_hints


class StackParams(TypedDict):
    UnsignedAuthorizerName: str
    UnsignedAuthorizerStatus: bool
    TableName: str
    SignedAuthorizerName: str
    SignedAuthorizerStatus: bool
    SignedAuthorizerTokenKeyName: str


get_type_hints(StackParams)
# {'UnsignedAuthorizerName': str, 'UnsignedAuthorizerStatus': bool, 'TableName': str, 'SignedAuthorizerName': str, 'SignedAuthorizerStatus': bool, 'SignedAuthorizerTokenKeyName': str}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can also declare a static method like this:

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class StockPrice(TypedDict):
    symbol: str
    year: int
    month: int
    day: int
    o: int
    h: int
    l: int
    c: int
    v: int | None

    @staticmethod# type: ignore
    def keys():
        return StockPrice.__dict__['__annotations__'].keys()
    
StockPrice.keys() 
#dict_keys(['symbol', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v'])
```